# Getting error while executing hive merge

Tags: hive

I am running below query:

```
MERGE INTO college_for_mrg AS T USING college AS S ON clg_name = clg_name 
WHEN MATCHED AND clg_id > 5 
THEN UPDATE SET clg_loc = "ind" 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT VALUES(2,"sd","dsd","dsfs");
```

Both the tables support acid properties.

I have also tried table name as `database_name.table_name` in query but still its giving the same error.

> error: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 cannot recognize input near
>   'MERGE' 'INTO' 'college_for_mrg'

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA ticket status is "IN PROGRESS"

[add support for MERGE statement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10924)

However it seems the development has finished recently

[Lefty Leverenz added a comment - 13/Jan/17 09:48

At this point MERGE is fully functional](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10924?focusedCommentId=15821516&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15821516)